# ColdFusion CFHTTP issue

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have the following code, but I keep getting connection failure.

```
<cfhttp method="GET" url="https://XXXXXX.fogbugz.com/api.asp" result="LogonAttempt">
    <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="cmd" value="logon" />
    <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="email" value="XXXXX"/>
    <cfhttpparam type="URL" name="password" value="XXXXXX"/>
</cfhttp>
```

If I make a call to Google or any other page it works fine. Any idea on how to fix this?

Using CF9

Comment: Your issue may be related to ColdFusion's certificate truststore: http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html

Comment: Do a cfdump on LogonAttempt - what exactly does it say?

Comment: I guess webservice URL is not accessible -  
It may due to certificate Issue or service is down.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check your url, I was able to confirm that my fogbuzz account was available by only switching the url and logon credentials. Tested in CF10 local instance.

To trouble shoot further please post at least the partial error or response.